# Dont understand this javascript function syntax

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain this javascript syntax.

What does n: { } mean?

Does it mean that AVSetFocus returns a nobject (which has been given the temporary name, n, which consists of 'fields' t, f and a.  t is an object (looks like), f is a function of the object t, and a is an array?

So AVSetFocus is returning an object and a function and an array.  Does this function actually call SetFocusToField?

What is this style called?

Bit confused.

```
function AVSetFocus(d, b) {
    return {
        n: {
            t: FocusMgr,
            f: FocusMgr.SetFocusToField,
            a: [d, b]
        }
    }
}
```

Just also found this:

```
var FocusMgr;

function FocusMgr_Init() {
    FocusMgr = new function () {
        this.mCurFocusID = 0;
        this.mCurFocusWindowID = 0;
        this.mCurFocusElement = null;
        this.mOpenedWindow = false;
        this.mFocusStk = [];
        //etc
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like minified code. You better should look into the original source to understand what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AvSetFocus()` function returns this object:

```
{
    n: {
        t: FocusMgr,
        f: FocusMgr.SetFocusToField,
        a: [d, b]
    }
}
```

The object has one property, `"n"`, which itself refers to another object:

```
    {
        t: FocusMgr,
        f: FocusMgr.SetFocusToField,
        a: [d, b]
    }
```

...which in turn has three properties. `"t"` refers to (presumably) yet another object, `"f"` refers to a method of same object `"t"` refers to, which seems a little redundant since you could access that via `""t`, and `"a"` ends up referring to an array of the two values passed into `AvSetFocus()` as parameters.

> *"Does this function actually call SetFocusToField?"*

No it doesn't. You might use it something like:

```
var avsf = AvSetFocus(x, y);
avsf.n.f();  // calls FocusMgr.SetFocusToField()
```

Or you could do this:

```
AvSetFocus(x, y).n.f();
```

As for what the parameters you pass to `AvSetFocus()` should be, I have no idea - from the code shown there's no way to tell.

Comment: But why would anyone not want to just set focus.  Why do 2 lines of code as above rather than simpler AVSetFocus(params);

Comment: I don't know. I'm just explaining the code that you've shown, I can't explain what the person who wrote it intended, especially when I don't know what the `FocusMgr` object is. Given you can set focus using the built-in DOM element [`.focus()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.focus) I don't know why you need a special custom function for it at all, but you wanted the syntax explained so at least now you know that much...

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that AVSetFocus returns a nobject (which has been given
>   the temporary name, n, which consists of 'fields' t, f and a. t is an
>   object (looks like), f is a function of the object t, and a is an
>   array?

`{}` is the object literal notation. It creates a new object. So yes you are correct.

The `f` variable is just a reference to the method, but it is not executed.

You can call the function by doing `n.f();`

Comment: Thanks for info but in this case the function is a library function and pretty sure that calling the function like AVSetFocus() does in fact set focus to the element.

Comment: No it does not call the FocusMgr.SetFocusToField. The f variable just refers to that function, but it is not called in any way.